# Compiz not handling Put movement corectly with dual monitor setup

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity on two monitors, both from the same model and set to 1080p resolution (in case this make a difference as in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134070/dual-monitor-and-12-04-snapping-window-to-full-screen-puts-the-window-on-other), **different problem** but somehow similar).

I am using Compiz¹ to improve my usage of this dual monitor setup², with a lot of helpful features.

My problem is with the Window Put functionality where you send a window to another monitor or viewport. It works on most cases, but sometimes it seems it's just trying to irritate me.

I set my keyboard shortcuts (relevant to this question) as following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+(<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>) to move a window to the *respective monitor*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+(<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>) to snap a window to the respective side of the *current monitor*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad X</kbd> to snap a window to a corner of the *current monitor*, being:

  - <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> the **bottom left** corner
  - <kbd>NumPad 3</kbd> the **bottom right** corner
  - <kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> the **top left** corner
  - <kbd>NumPad 9</kbd> the **top right** corner

I have 3 simple test cases to demonstrate³ this.

## Test 1 - Putting a Floating Window to the other monitor

[image]

> *WORKS!*

Here I am changing the window from one monitor to the other with no problem.

## Test 2 - Putting a Side Snapped Window to the other monitor

[image]

> *WORKS!*

Here I first I snap the window to one side *(full monitor height, half monitor width)* and then send it to the other monitor.

It goes where it's expected to.

## Test 3 - Putting a Corner Snapped Window  to the other monitor

[image: not working]

> *DOESN'T WORK!*

Here I snap the window to a corner *(half monitor height, half monitor width)* and then send it to the other monitor.

It actually goes and place it self there, but out of sudden it comes back where it was on the first monitor. You can see I didn't press anything to come back.

## Workaround

[image: workaround]
As you can see on this animation, the only way I could find to deal with it is *really annoying*.

I have to snap at the side, send to the other monitor, and then send it to the corner I want.

Is there any way to solve this **very annoying** issue?

---

## OBS

¹ In case it helps, I exported my Compiz profile [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/EXFg3yux).

² I didn't record the full viewport from both monitors, but you can identify them looking for the "backgroud cut" near the center of the animation. (I have a dual monitor wallpaper so it might not be trivial to identify it on the first look).

³ I am using [screenkey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screenkey/) to show you what I am really pressing.

Comment: 1+ For the **very** nice formatting!

Comment: @AndroidDev Thank you, I know it helps :D. I might not have much reputation, but I am an active user here

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit Ha interesting nickname. Patrick I agree it's very nice formatting. Another 10+ on your way to breaking past 150 over your seven years and five months.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you. At this point I already gave up on having an answer. Plus, this problem is not something that I have to deal multiple times a day like when I posted. But I let the question here just in case it can help someone with the same problem.